# Spring JDBC NullPointerException on INSERT Statement

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jdbc, nullpointerexception, vaadin

I'm working on a Maven, Spring-Boot, Vaadin Project and i can not resolve a NullPointerException when i try to create a new entity in my university table.

I creating a new View and bind all together but if i want to execute my saveUniversity() function with the example values it always throws a NullPointerException. Hope this is all relevant code.

### AddUniversityView.java

```
public class AddUniversityView extends VerticalLayout {

private TextField name = new TextField("Name");
private TextField city = new TextField("City");
private TextField country = new TextField("Country");

private Button save = new Button("Save", e -> saveUniversity()); // Line 23

Binder<University> binder = new Binder<>();

private University university = new University();

@Autowired
private UniversityService universityService;

public AddUniversityView() {

    add(name, city, country, save);



    /**
     * Some values for example
     */
    name.setValue("LMU");
    city.setValue("Muenchen");
    country.setValue("Deutschland"); 


    binder.bind(name, University::getName, University::setName);
    binder.bind(city, University::getCity, University::setCity);
    binder.bind(country, University::getCountry, University::setCountry);
}

public void saveUniversity() {
    binder.setBean(university);
    System.out.println(binder.getBean().toString());
    universityService.create(university); // Line 109
    clearFields();
}

public void clearFields() {
    binder.readBean(null);
}
```

### UniversityService

```
@Service
public class UniversityService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void create(University university) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO university (name, city, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
                university.getName(), university.getCity(), university.getCountry());
    }
}
```

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://localhost/univers
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

### univers Database

```
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_univers |
+-------------------+
| student           |
| university        |
+-------------------+
```

### university column

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city    | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sandrofriedrich.ui.views.university.AddUniversityView.saveUniversity(AddUniversityView.java:109) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sandrofriedrich.ui.views.university.AddUniversityView.lambda$0(AddUniversityView.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:133) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:327) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$5ee67f2b$1(ComponentEventBus.java:191) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:379) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:379) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:377) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$0(ServerRpcHandler.java:367) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:367) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:309) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1486) ~[flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:300) [flow-server-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:356) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Assuming `universityService.create(university);` is really the line 109, did you try to run the debugger and check if `universityService` is `null`, and if so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you create the `AddUniversityView`?

If it's used with a `@Route` annotation, or if it is also autowired in some other class, it should work.

However, if you instantiate it yourself, as in `new AddUniversityView()`, autowiring will not work.

Comment: thank you this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

@Autowired means, somebody from outside will set this field. "Private" on the other hand means nobody except this class is allowed to use it.

You should change your code like this

```
@Autowired
UniversityService universityService;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Spring is perfectly capable of autowiring `private` fields.